# Reroute Bluetooth speaker power

Tags: voltage, power, pcb

I have a Blaupunkt Bluetooth soundbar where the USB 5V cable is broken (the plug is indefinitely broken no repair possible.)

My thought was to remove the 3.7V battery and use the cable to solder my 3.7V powersupply to it.

Would this be something that is possible? It seems logical to me that this is indeed possible.

I can post a picture of the PCB but I can't find the schematic of it online.
I'm not sure if a picture would be able give the solution.

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible. Yes, consumer devices don't come with schematics and you usually have to draw them yourself if you need them.

Comment: Is the **plug** broken (that's part of the cable) or is the **jack** broken (the hole in the speaker where you plug in the cable?)

Comment: If the device doesn't pay too much attention to battery management and there is no other power source, such a thing is typically *possible*.  A little more awareness of the voltage range of such cells would suggest that around 4 volts may be a better mid-range voltage for a battery eliminator.  Ultimately however, questions on the repair or modification of *undocumented consumer products* are not on topic here.

Comment: If it is the plug on the cable that is broken, you could cut it off and put on a new one. If the thingy on the soundbar where you plug in the cable is broken, you could solder in a new one, or solder the wires of a USB cable directly to the PCB. If all that is not an option, you could google for "3.7V "battery eliminator"" and get one, or solder directly to the battery connections, never connect another power source, and hope the battery management in the soundbar doesn't get in the way.

Comment: As long as you're getting out your soldering iron, and you've disassembled it enough to take a picture of the PCB, it would be much better to solder a cable (with a USB plug on the far end) to the PCB contact points associated with the damaged USB jack. That will preserve the ability to run on batteries as well as when plugged in.

Comment: Soldering is not an option. It broke of the PCB and the paths are gone. 
I'll try the eliminator!